# asking if 2 doubles are not equal - a!=b

Tags: floating-point

i know that if you want to check for equality for doubles you do:
`return abs(a-b)<EPSILON`

my question is: is that comparison to EPSILON also needed when i want to ask if `a!=b`?
my intuition says yes (because they might be equal), but from what i saw on the web it is not implemented with EPSILON

and one more question, what is the reason we use `EPSILON` when we want to check for equality in doubles or floats?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the most common way to compare two doubles is the following (C++ code), becuase during the computation you can introduce errors due to cancellation, finite precision representation and other (for more details see [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://www-users.math.umd.edu/~jkolesar/mait613/floating_point_math.pdf))

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <cmath>
#include <limits>
bool almostEqual(double const a, double const b)
{
  double const diff = sta::abs(a - b);
  double const toll = std::max(std::abs(a), std::abs(b)) * 
                         std::numeric_limits<double>::epsilon();
  return diff < toll;
}
```

Then two doubles are different if they aren't almost equals, so `a!=b` become `!almostEqual(a,b)`.

Answer (score 3):

You use epsilon because floating point numbers aren't *always* exact.  You can't represent 1/3 exactly as a decimal number; you can't represent 0.1 exactly as a binary number.

Check the absolute value of the difference against an epsilon is sufficient; there's no need for anything else.

I'd recommend reading [this](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html).

Comment: Have **you** read the article (I haven't)? Quote: "Incidentally, some people think that the solution to such anomalies is never to compare floating-point numbers for equality, but instead to consider them equal if they are within some error bound E. **This is hardly a cure-all because it raises as many questions as it answers.** What should the value of E be? If x < 0 and y > 0 are within E, should they really be considered to be equal, even though they have different signs? Furthermore, the relation defined by this rule, a ~ b  |a - b| < E, is not an equivalence relation [snip]"

Comment: I disagree with the wording "floating-point numbers aren't exact".  Floating-point numbers **are** exact, they just can't represent all real numbers.

Comment: I haven't memorized the article.  What would you propose as a cure-all?  What does the article offer as the be-all, end-all?

Answer (score 0):

You don't *have* to check for equality that way. Due to inexact representations, accumulating precision errors, etc., you almost certainly will want to. Good discussion of relative and absolute errors [here](http://www.cygnus-software.com/papers/comparingfloats/Comparing%20floating%20point%20numbers.htm).

Answer (score 0):

Checking for float/double equality:

```
abs(a - b) <= EPSILON
```

Checking for float/double in-equality:

```
abs(a - b) > EPSILON
```